# Rosdep failed to detect argparse (Debian)

Tags: python, rosdep, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to build ROS hydro/groovy (recently switched to hydro upon hearing that groovy may have had more than its fair share of bugs) on Debian Jesse and have been having a lot of trouble getting rosdep to run all the way through. I tried skipping rosdep and just manually installing the packages with apt-get when the catkin build process stalled on a missing package, but once I thought I got them all it got bogged down in a mess of linking errors. This made me think rosdep maybe was doing something other than just getting apt-get to fill all of the dependencies. I finally managed to build collada-dom-dev and so rosdep would stop failing there but now it fails to find python argparse. It's my understanding that argparse is provided by python 2.7 (the library libpython2.7-stdlib specifically) which I verified by checking packages.debian.org/jessie/python-argparse. Does anyone know how to get rosdep to recognize that python contains argparse and to link the libraries there? I will update the wiki with everything I learn from your responses!

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78231/rosdep-failed-to-detect-argparse-(debian)/) by [St3am](https://answers.ros.org/users/6506/st3am/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to contribut a patch to the [rosdep rules](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) for debian.  The easiest will be to alias a request for argparse to install lipython2.7-stdlib for jessie while leaving the rule to use python-argparse for squeeze and wheezy.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dave.peacock](https://answers.ros.org/users/12111/dave.peacock/) on 2014-02-18**:
I'm  not the OP, but just submitted a pull request with the patch, tested with squeeze

**Comment by [btsimonh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25169/btsimonh/) on 2015-11-24**:
Just installing on arm - still getting 'python-argparse has no installation candidate' on wheezy armhf (mk802ii) - hoping it's in libpython2.7-stdlib...

**Comment by [btsimonh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25169/btsimonh/) on 2015-11-25**:
the build completed with no errors.